# Snowflake Query Profile - Total Execution Time

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We ran a query in Snowflake that reported a "Total Execution Time" of 3 minutes and 50 seconds. After looking at the query profile to see which nodes were taking the most time, the "Most Expensive Nodes" only added up to 159 ms. The remaining nodes could only add up to a max of 296 ms. So we have a possible total of 455 ms or just under half a second. Where could the other 3 minutes and 49 seconds of "Total Execution Time" be coming from? Here are a couple snip-its of the query profile.

[Total Execution Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeNLX.png)

[Most Expensive Nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3qPW.png)

Answer (score 0):

does your query have multiple phases like 1001,2001 at the top. This can happen when the warehouse has a execution failure, and is restarted. This one one cause of super long total executions. This can happen if after a release you execution was started on the latest version of the software, but is rolled back to prior versions in the case of failure.

But most likely the system was waiting on a locked table.

Both of these should be observable by listing the [query execution stats](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html) for the ID of the query.

Comment: There's only one phase in the query profile. I got the query execution stats and it's not reporting anything for the "TRANSACTION_BLOCKED_TIME". The only thing I found odd while looking at the query profile in live time was the bytes scanned. It was stuck at 97% for majority of the total execution time. There's also no queueing time.

Comment: Also want to add that there is no spilling to local or remote storage. I can run the same query over and over again so that all data is scanned from the cache, but still taking over three minutes to run even though the nodes add up to under half a second.

Comment: @IADataPlatform if the totals of the columns of the `QUERY_HISTORY` do not add up to any where near the total, I would file a bug report